# Is it possible to make Google Chrome Canary default browers on OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-yosemite

It was my default browser previously but it doesnt work anymore. please see screenshot of the settings below.

> This is a secondary installation of Google Chrome, and cannot be made
>   your default browser.

[image]

Comment: Does Canary appear in your Safari prefs - General tab / Default Web Browser ? ( https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/8msHCzXjeVc/discussion )

Comment: just chrome not canary

Comment: What about in Mac System Preferences / General ?

Comment: @nolawipetros lucky you, you got back your bounty ^^)

Comment: no problem, not your fault. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like other people have encountered this issue already.

One solution I found [here](http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/set-chrome-canary-default-browser-windows-mac.html) (pre-yosemite):

> For Mac users all you need to do is run Safari and then head to preferences and change the “Default web browser” to Canary from the dropdown menu.

And this has been asked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/625879/how-can-i-set-google-chrome-canary-as-the-default-browser-on-windows-8) for windows as well, and this is mentioned for **yosemite**:

> In OSX Yosmite 10.10.3 - System Preferences -> General -> Default web browser (set to Google Chrome Canary)

Does any of the above work for you?

Comment: yes- in system preferences

Comment: I dont see Canary in this options :/ Any more suggestions?

Comment: did you try both suggestions?